# How to retain data for only a few recent days in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle

Due to space limitation, I need to retain my data only for a few recent days before the disk space is full. what's the best practice to do that?

Can I trigger a job when the available disk space reaches a specific amount?

Comment: What volume of data (i.e. number of records, average record size, tablespace size) are we talking about here?

Comment: as I checked the only data file of the tablespace it grows 2.5TB per day

Comment: and it might help to mention that fortunately I have date columns that can be used to detect older data.

Comment: 2.5 terabytes *per day*?

Comment: yes Jeffrey 2.5 Terabytes per day, big data, right?

Comment: What's the total capacity of your disk drives, may I ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on [partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm).

If you have a partitioned table with one partition per day, you can easily schedule a job to drop the oldest partition every X day.

Comment: Oh so I believe I have two distinct problems: 1-Can Oracle check if the disk space is almost full and data clean up is necessary and trigger a job or something? and 2-what the best way to clean up the old data. your answer addresses the latter question clearly thanks, what about the former one?

Comment: I don't believe there is such a trigger provided by Oracle itself, you have to write one your self. Also, I would recomend letting the requirements determine how many days you should keep, and size the system accordingly, and go for a simple rolling window scheme where you keep X nr of days and drop off the oldest every day.